# Show that $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt p]$ is an ordered Integral Domain.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integral-domain

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt p]=\{ a+b\sqrt p ~| a,b\in \mathbb{Z},p~is~prime\} $

Assume $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt p]$ ia an integral domain with usual addition and multiplication.
Show $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt p]$ is an ordered integral domain with respect to $P=\{ a+b\sqrt p ~|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}  ~~~ and ~~~ a+b\sqrt p ~~is~~a~positive~real~number \}$.
I know we are only expected to show for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt p] $ exactly on of the following holds $x\in P$ , $x=0$, or $-x\in P$ but I don't Know how to show that.

Comment: Don't forget that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}] \subset \mathbb{R}$. You know stuff about $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Stylistic side-note: "$p$ is prime" should be outside the curly braces in the definition of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt p]$

Comment: You are also supposed to show that $P$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Both properties also follow from *g1c*s observation.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood the question, just observing $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}]\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$ should work.